# remove parenthesis alone in the java string

Tags: java, regex

In my java string eg:hello(world) is there. I want to remove the paranthesis alone the result should be **helloworld** .

I tryied the regexpression like this

```
String strFunction = Hello(world);

strFunction.replaceAll("\\)\\(\\s+", "");
```

But it is notworking,please help it out

Comment: For that string i want to remove the parantheses and white space if i give the both in same expression it not working (eg:strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[)(]\\s+", "")) so i changed this to two expression noew its working like this strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[)(]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Yes john i give the soluction for my question in the comment . Thanks John

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, so you need to re-assign the result back to the original string. Also, there is some issue with your regex. Currently it will try to replace those brackets if they occur back to back.

You need to use a character class:

```
strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[)(]", "");
```

Comment: For that string i want to remove the parantheses and white space if i give the both in same expression it not working (eg:strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[)(]\\s+", "")) so i changed this to two expression noew its working like this strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[)(]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");

Comment: @mohammedabuthaheer. You can use `*` quantifier instead of `+`. `strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[)(]\\s*", ""))`, now it will match 0 or more space after parenthesis, which is your current state.

Answer (score 2):

```
strFunction = strFunction.replaceAll("[(\\s)]", "");
```

- Assign the result back to your string reference.
- Use a character class `[]`. (Note: you don't need to escape `()` in there.)

Answer (score 0):

It remove all parenthesis whether they are balanced or not.

```
String replaced = "(4+5)+6".replaceAll("[()]", "");
```